# Select siblings of siblings in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

In the following code, when the user clicks on the `'.more'` span element, I want to retrieve information (eg, the ID) from the `img` within the `article` tag using jQuery.

Here's the HTML:

```
<article>
<img src="..." id="TR"/>
<div>some text <a>link</a> <span class="more">read more</span></div>
</article>
```

I've tried this code:

```
   $('.more').click(function () {

        var id = $(this).siblings().siblings('img').attr('id');

});
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Many thanks!

Comment: my uncle isn't my brother... (unless I have a really screwed up family)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
$(".more").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("article").find("img:first").attr("id");
});
```

This looks up the parent tree for the containing `<article>` tag.  Then, it finds the first `<img>` tag in that and gets its id value.

You can't use `.siblings()` on `$(this)` because the image isn't a direct sibling of `$(this)`.  You could use `.siblings()` if you got the right parent that the img was a sibling of, but that's a little more fragile than what I've proposed.  For example, this would also work, but it relies on more precise positioning of the HTML objects and any slight edits could break this code:

```
$(".more").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().prev().attr("id");
});
```

or

```
$(".more").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().siblings("img").attr("id");
});
```

You can't use `.closest()` on the `<img>` tag directly because the img isn't a parent of the `.more` object.

If this were my code, I'd do it like this because it's the most flexible and the least likely to break if the HTML is edited slightly and you're sure to get the right img object, even if there are more images nearby:

```
<article>
<img class="target" src="..." id="TR"/>
<div>some text <a>link</a> <span class="more">read more</span></div>
</article>

$(".more").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("article").find(".target").attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parent().siblings() instead of siblings().siblings()

```
$('.more').click(function () { 
    var left = $(this).parent().siblings('img').attr('id');
    alert(left);
});
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8FkD/)

Comment: FYI to the OP, with an innocuous editing of the HTML (such as surrounding something with a `<span>` or adding another level of `<div>` to achieve some formatting/style goal) this code could easily break.  I prefer my JS/jQuery to be more robust than that, using specific classes as targets rather than exact parent/sibling positioning so normal tweaking of the HTML could happen and the jQuery wouldn't break.

Comment: I dig your concern jfriend00. I chose this code because it was the closest to what I already had. I would accept both as answers if I could. But I'll go with yours as your point is well made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular class selector:

```
$('article > img[id]').attr('id');
```

Comment: given that there is only ever one `article`.

Comment: Ah then it's best to use the other answer. I oversimplified :)